# For which value of $a$ is the matrix is isometric?

Tags: linear-algebra

> For  which value  of $a$  is the matrix   $\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\1 &1\ \end{pmatrix}$ is isometrics   ?

My attempt : For isometric it must be  unitary so $a = -1$

Is its true ?

Comment: What mean "a Matrix being isometric" ? Do you mean "it's the matrix of an isometry" ?

Comment: @Surb i mean matrix is isometry  when matrix is unitary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\1 &1\ \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\y\ \end{pmatrix}$ and  $\begin{pmatrix} x \\y\ \end{pmatrix}$ have the same length .

Then $a^2x^2+(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2$ which is  not possible for all $x$ and $y$.